# Flutter - Handler != null is not true

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Can anyone explain me this error log

```
Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/semantics/semantics.dart': Failed assertion: line 2847 pos 12: 'handler != null': is not true
```

It does not affect in any screen but this does keep coming when I change child of a certain controller through `setState((){})`.

Thanks for your help,

Comment: What you have used in the parent widget: MaterialApp or WidgetsApp?

Comment: I have used MaterialApp

Comment: just wrap the MaterialApp with ExcludeSemantics widget.

Comment: yeah, that worked. Actually it was not causing any problem in the flow but still the logs were just horrifying. Thanks ;-) @SanketVekariya

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If parent widget is WidgetApp, change it to Material as most of the widget results in the same exception because of their must needed parent: MaterialApp.
If MaterialApp is already there and still resulting with the exception, wrap it with "ExcludeSemantics" widget.
Check out this [link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Semantics/excludeSemantics.html) for more...

Comment: Thank you, I could make this work, but I don't get it why this occurred in the first place. And I don't think I should exclude the semantics.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a String to the Text constructor

Comment: I already have passed String to every Text Constructor I have called.